# Nestable - allow reorder only for siblings with same parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [Nestable](http://dbushell.github.io/Nestable/) to let the user edit his custom menu.

But for a dragged item it should NOT be allowed to switch the parent element.

Example from the demo:
- user can reorder elements 6,7,8 but they cannot leave element 5
- user can reorder elements 3,4,5,9,10 but they cannot leave element 2

I already removed the complete logic within the ["if" for moving horizontal](https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable/blob/master/jquery.nestable.js#L357).

I think the relevant places to add this logic is [here, where "before" and "after" are used](https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable/blob/master/jquery.nestable.js#L440) in "move vertical":

```
else if (before) {
    this.pointEl.before(this.placeEl);
}
else {
    this.pointEl.after(this.placeEl);
}
```

I tried it like this:

```
else if (before) {
    var a = this.placeEl.parent(); //element I dragged (?)
    var b = this.pointEl.parent(); //element the mouse hovers over at the moment
    if (a.parent() === b.parent()){
        // a and b are in the same <ol>, so allow drop
        this.pointEl.before(this.placeEl);
    }
}
```

But it's not working. Any suggestions?